# IntelliJ-could not find "package" required by:project

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea

I am having problem in adding `org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2` dependency into my gradle project using IntelliJ IDEA.

I added the implementation `org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2` into my gradle script and intellij automatically started download of dependency and it finish successfully.

But when I start to build the project it  fails and display this message Could not find `org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:.`
Required by:
project :

When I go to project structure and to Libraries this is how it is displayed
[image]

Comment: Looks like it is missing a version number.

Comment: Yes, you were right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add a version number